Configurar Presentacion, Instalador e Inicio con VB.Net y SQLite
Tengo una aplicación desarrollando en VB.net con Visual Studio 2022, en la que quiero que al ejecutarse muestre inicial el formulario de presentación(FormNuevaPresentacion) por un lapso de 10 segundos, se tiene que cerrar y luego mostrar (con la condición de si no hay datos en la tabla TB_Registrarse, si hay datos no se tiene que mostrar) el formulario de instalación(FormInstaladorESTEMATI) para cargar todos los procedimientos de mi aplicación desde una tabla SQLite(TB_EventosAlmacenados, columna 'EVENTOS_ALMACENADOS'), dos ProgressBar, uno para la cantidad de filas de la tabla y el otro para el porcentaje de carga, terminado esto me muestra un Label  Me.LblFinalInstaler.Visible = True y un botón(btnSalirInstalador) para cerrar este formulario y mostrar el formulario de inicio(Mdi) FormInicioAgroQuimicaSolutions, en My.Settings.Aplication configuré como Formulario de inicio: FormInicioAgroQuimicaSolutions y como presentacion: FormNuevaPresentacion, tengo diversos inconvenientes con el código, no consigo implementar como lo mencionado arriba, me muestra el FormNuevaPresentacion al inico, luego aparece el FormInicioAgroQuimicaSolutions y el instalador aparece por dos 0 tres segundos por detrás del form presentacion y cerrarse, a lo que este(presentación) queda como congelado sin cerrarse, no consigo que el FormInstalador se ejecute normalmente, no sé si erré en la configuración de My.Settings.Aplication o en el código, si alguien me pueda orientar que está mal, paso el codigo, FormNuevaPresentacion,
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices

Public Class FormNuevaPresentacion
    Private Sub FormNuevaPresentacion_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Width = 620
        Me.Height = 380
        Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
        TimerNuevaPresent.Interval = 1000 ' Intervalo del temporizador: 1 segundo
        TimerNuevaPresent.Start()

    End Sub

    Private TiempoTranscurrido As Integer = 0
    Private Const TiempoDeseado As Integer = 3000 ' Tiempo deseado en milisegundos
    Private Sub TimerNuevaPresent_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TimerNuevaPresent.Tick
        TiempoTranscurrido += TimerNuevaPresent.Interval
        If TiempoTranscurrido > TiempoDeseado Then
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
            Me.Close()
            TiempoTranscurrido = 0
            TimerNuevaPresent.Stop()
        End If
    End Sub

End Class`;  Este es FormInstaladorESTEMATI: `Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SQLite
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement

Public Class FormInstaladorESTEMATI
    Public conn As New SQLiteConnection(DatabaseHelper.GetDatabaseConnectionString())
    Private Sub FormInstaladorESTEMATI_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Call HayDatosEnTablaRegistrarse()
        Me.Width = 950
        Me.Height = 550
        Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen

        Me.LblFinalInstaler.Visible = False
        Me.PictBoxCantidadEventos.Visible = False
        Me.PictBoxPorcentajeEventos.Visible = False
        Me.PictBoxTotalEventosAlmacen.Visible = False

        Me.TimerInstaladorApp.Start()

        'Call CargarEventosAlmacenados()

    End Sub

    Private Sub HayDatosEnTablaRegistrarse()
        Try
            If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                conn.Open()
            End If

            Dim cmd As New SQLiteCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TB_Registrarse", conn)
            Dim count As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())

            ' Mostrar el formulario correspondiente
            If count = 0 Then
                ' Si no hay datos, mostrar el formulario de instalación
                Me.Show()
            Else
                ' Si hay datos, mostrar el formulario de inicio
                Dim frmInicioAgraQuiicaSolutions As New FormInicioAgroQuimicaSolutions
                frmInicioAgraQuiicaSolutions.Show()
            End If
            conn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                conn.Close()
            End If
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Async Sub CargarEventosAlmacenados()
        Try
            Me.Show()
            ' Simular una operación asíncrona, como la carga de datos desde una base de datos
            Await Task.Delay(100) ' Simulación de retardo de 100 milisegundos
            ' Abrir la conexión
            If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                conn.Open()
            End If
            ' Consulta SQL para obtener procedimientos
            Dim query As String = "SELECT EVENTOS_ALMACENADOS FROM TB_EventosAlmacenados"
            ' Crear un comando SQL
            Dim command As New SQLiteCommand(query, conn)
            ' Ejecutar el comando y obtener un lector de datos
            Dim reader As SQLiteDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
            ' Obtiene el número total de filas
            Dim totalRows As Integer = 415
            Dim currentRow As Integer = 0
            While reader.Read()
                ' Procesa cada fila de la consulta
                Dim evento As String = reader("EVENTOS_ALMACENADOS").ToString()
                ' Actualizar los elementos visuales de forma segura
                Dim porcentajeCompleto As Double = (currentRow / totalRows) * 100
                If InvokeRequired Then
                    Invoke(Sub()
                               txtEventosAlmacenados.Text = evento
                               LblPorcentajeEventos.Text = $"Carga {porcentajeCompleto.ToString("F2")} %"
                               LblCantidadEventos.Text = $"Cargadas {currentRow} de {totalRows} lineas"
                               PgssEventosAlmacenados.Value = CInt(porcentajeCompleto)
                               PgssBarPorcentajeEventos.Value = CInt(porcentajeCompleto) ' Actualizar PgssBarPorcentajeEventos

                           End Sub)
                Else
                    txtEventosAlmacenados.Text = evento
                    LblPorcentajeEventos.Text = $"Carga {porcentajeCompleto.ToString("F2")} %"
                    LblCantidadEventos.Text = $"Cargadas {currentRow} de {totalRows} lineas"
                    PgssEventosAlmacenados.Value = CInt(porcentajeCompleto)
                    PgssEventosAlmacenados.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
                    PgssBarPorcentajeEventos.Value = CInt(porcentajeCompleto) ' Actualizar PgssBarPorcentajeEventos
                    PgssBarPorcentajeEventos.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
                End If
                ' Simular un retardo para que puedas ver el progreso
                Await Task.Delay(100)
                currentRow += 1
            End While
            If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                conn.Close()
            End If
            txtEventosAlmacenados.Text = ""
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
        End Try
    End Sub


    Private Sub TimerInstaladorApp_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TimerInstaladorApp.Tick
        Dim txtEventosAlmacenados As New Windows.Forms.TextBox
        Static tiempo As Integer = 0
        Const tiempoTotal As Integer = 50000 ' Tiempo total en milisegundos
        Dim eventos As Integer = 415
        ' Actualizar el progreso de la barra
        PgssEventosAlmacenados.Value = CInt((tiempo / tiempoTotal) * 100)
        LblCantidadEventos.Text = $"Cargadas {CInt((tiempo / tiempoTotal) * eventos)} de {eventos}"
        ' Mostrar u ocultar los PictureBox según el progreso de la carga
        If PgssEventosAlmacenados.Value = 100 Then
            PictBoxCantidadEventos.Visible = True
            PictBoxPorcentajeEventos.Visible = True
            PictBoxTotalEventosAlmacen.Visible = True
            Dim lastLoadedRow As Integer = 0
            ' Actualizar el TextBox con la última fila cargada desde la tabla
            txtEventosAlmacenados.Text = lastLoadedRow.ToString()
        End If
        ' Verificar si se alcanzó el tiempo total
        If tiempo >= tiempoTotal Then
            ' Realizar las acciones finales al completarse la carga
            TimerInstaladorApp.Stop()
            Me.LblFinalInstaler.Visible = True

        End If
        ' Incrementar el tiempo del Timer
        tiempo += TimerInstaladorApp.Interval

        Me.Hide()

    End Sub

End Class`; Aqui FormInicioAgroQuimicaSolutions:  `Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.SQLite
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text
Imports Timer = System.Windows.Forms.Timer

Public Class FormInicioAgroQuimicaSolutions
    Public conn As New SQLiteConnection(DatabaseHelper.GetDatabaseConnectionString())

    Private Sub ShowNewForm(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles NUEVONewToolStripButton.Click
        ' Cree una nueva instancia del formulario secundario.
        Dim ChildForm As New System.Windows.Forms.Form
        ' Conviértalo en un elemento secundario de este formulario MDI antes de mostrarlo.
        ChildForm.MdiParent = Me

        m_ChildFormNumber += 1
        ChildForm.Text = "Ventana " & m_ChildFormNumber

        ChildForm.Show()
    End Sub

    Private WithEvents tmrShowMainForm As Timer
    Private Sub FormInicioAgroQuimicaSolutions_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Me.Width = 1450
        Me.Height = 775
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        Me.Text = ModuleTitulosForm.TitulosForm
        Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        Me.MaximizeBox = False
        Me.MinimizeBox = False
        Me.IsMdiContainer = True
        '---------------------------------------------------
        Me.NUEVONewToolStripButton.Enabled = False
        Me.ABRIROpenToolStripButton.Enabled = False
        Me.GUARDARSaveToolStripButton.Enabled = False
        Me.IMPRIMIRPrintToolStripButton.Enabled = False
        '---------------------------------------------------
        Me.VENTASToolStripMenuItem1.Enabled = False
        Me.PROVEEDORESToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
        Me.EMPLEADOSToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
        Me.INVENTARIOToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
        Me.INGRESARPRODUCTOSToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
        Me.CONFIGURACIÓNToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
        Me.MANTENIMIENTOToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
        Me.LISTAToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
        Me.INICIOSESIÓNToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
        Me.TStpMenItemRegistrarse.Enabled = False

        ' Mostrar el formulario de presentación
        Dim frmNuevaPresentacion As New FormNuevaPresentacion
        frmNuevaPresentacion.ShowDialog()
        frmNuevaPresentacion.Dispose()

        Call HayDatosEnTablaRegistrarse()

        '----------------------------------------------------
        'If Not My.Settings.ProductoRegistrado Then
        '    ' La aplicación no está registrada
        '    If My.Settings.PrimerRegistro Then
        '        ' Es la primera vez que se abre la aplicación
        '        My.Settings.DiasDePrueba = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30)
        '        My.Settings.PrimerRegistro = False
        '        My.Settings.DiasVencimiento = DateTime.Now.AddDays(730)
        '        My.Settings.Save()
        '        'MostrarFormularioTiempoVencimiento()

        '    Else
        '        ' La aplicación ya se ha abierto antes
        '        ComprobarEstadoLicencia()
        '    End If
        'Else
        '    ' La aplicación está registrada
        '    MostrarMensajeBienvenida()
        'End If
        'Me.Show()
        'Me.ResumeLayout(True)

    End Sub

    Private Sub HayDatosEnTablaRegistrarse()
        Try
            If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                conn.Open()
            End If

            Dim cmd As New SQLiteCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TB_Registrarse", conn)
            Dim count As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())

            ' Mostrar el formulario correspondiente
            If count = 0 Then
                ' Si no hay datos, mostrar el formulario de instalación
                Using frmInstaladorESTEMATI As New FormInstaladorESTEMATI
                    frmInstaladorESTEMATI.ShowDialog()
                End Using
            Else
                Me.INICIOSESIÓNToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
                Me.TStpMenItemRegistrarse.Enabled = True
            End If

            conn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                conn.Close()
            End If
        End Try

    End Sub`  


La explicación me parece confusa, favor mejorar la redacción

Estas describiendo dos escenarios diferentes.. uno es un splash screen, que no es lo que vos queres, y otro un formulario que se inicie solo la primera vez, que no veo en esa marañan de codigo ilimitada donde podria estar... por favor, usa un [mcve] para que podamos ayudarte...

gbianchi<> Lo quedescribí es mostrar el FormNuevaPresntacion por 10 segundos  y luego si hay datos en la tabla TB_EventosAlmacenados se muestre el FormInicioAgroQuimicaSolutions(formulario Mdi) y NO se muestre el FormInstaladorESTEMATI y si no hay datos en la tabla TB_EventosAlmacenados SI se muestre el FormInstaladorESTEMATI hasta que termine su proceso(cargar eventos de la App desde una tabla) una vez finalizado esto cerrar este formulario y mostrar el FormInicioAgroQuimicaSolutions. Espero haber sido claro y haberme hecho entender. Gracias por contestar. Me queda solo esto para terminar.-
